# Android Studio Log

Tags: android-studio

Is it possible to view just the log output generated by my application. I know I can use Log.i etc. but that only applies to items specifically logged. Often during an exception, I struggle just to read the text as the logs keep filling up with system events

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question when I answered. So you want items related to your application to be logged even if you don't specifically log them? And you want only these without other system events?

Comment: @AdamJohns That's correct

Comment: What about raising the log level? To something like info or error. That way a ton of system events won't show up, and you don't have to specifically log something to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to filter on your application's specific log events, simply enter the **package name of your app** into the filter (the search box) for the LogCat. Additionally, change the log level to Error (to avoid seeing informative messages).